# Cached JS file loaded incomplete

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, google-chrome, firefox, caching

I have dynamic-generated JS files. When browser loads this file for the first time (it does not exist in browser cache) it is loaded properly. But when browser loads this file from local cache, it is incomplete. I found that it happens only for larger files that are sent chunked (transfer-encoding: chunked).

File: https://www.venuspuzzle.com/html/custom.js
Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 08 Nov 2017 13:33:33 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
cache-control: public, max-age=31536000
expires: Wed, 07 Nov 2018 18:54:29 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 07 Nov 2017 18:54:29 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8
```

On first load, file is complete (it has about 119kB), but when you reload it (F5, cmd+R), it has only 72kB and is incomplete. That happens in some browsers (Firefox, Edge) also when you reload whole page.

Additional info: I use htaccess to compress and cache JS files, so there are javascript-related commands from htaccess:

```
AddType text/javascript .js
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 14 days"
```

Does anyone have idea what's the problem? Other JS resources that are small (like 53kB) are working well (e.g. https://www.venuspuzzle.com/wizard/venus-order-wizard.js)

Comment: That might very well be an issue with gzip encoding, try to disable them and see what happens. I had few times similar issues and they were all related to server configuration (gzip encoding / wrong permissions etc.)

Comment: I tried to disable gzip for JS files and it worked. But on the other side we need gzip to be enabled because of page performance. And the problem is that it is not working only for large files, small resources are cached properly.

Comment: Well you need to check apache config and verify where is the exact problem. You might change tags to target apache. There are a lots of resources online that describe the same problem. Another solution would be to serve pre-gziped assets from apache.. Something like this:
https://gist.github.com/bhollis/2200790
Benefits are that apache doesn't need to compress files on each request, and the files can be gziped with maximum compression (I'm using this approach almost always)